# scope issue with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm having a page with some inline css & javascript, the javascript on the original page contains some click and scroll logic which looks like this

```
$('#abc').on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').scrollTop($('#xyz').offset().top)
});
```

it works fine on the original page;

Now I'm having a new page, which imports the original page as an iframe on the new page, but because it is iframe, the scope of the javascript code on original page inside this iframe is now bind to the iframe itself, and because it's bind to iframe itself, the $('html, body').scrollTop no longer works...

Is there anyway I can modify the original page to make it work through iframe?

Comment: you mean that the carrier page and the iframe page are on the same website and you can code them to your liking?

Comment: yea, I have access to the new page, and I can ask someone to update the original page

Comment: I may have something for that, I have to search my archives

Comment: kk, thx! I look forward to it!

Comment: added an answer... some questions?

Comment: @MisterJojo I see, thx! I was trying to use window.parent.scrollTo, but it's giving me cors issue, I guess postMessage doesn't have cors issue

Answer (score 1):

for obvious security reasons, iframes are isolated in their own sandbox.

however, if you are in control of the code of the parent page and the iframe page, then you can use the message mechanism and pass your information through the event.data part.

here the example only passes text, for more extensive data, use JSON.stringify () / JSON.parse ()

> file **z1.html** (parent)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Z1</title>
  <style>
#iFrameZ2 { width: 400px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid red; }
#receiveTxt { margin: .5em; border: 1px solid blue; padding: .2em; width: 15em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h4>main page (z1.html)</h4>

  <input type="text" id="messageTxt" placeholder="a message...">
  <button id="btSender">send to iframe</button>
  <div id="receiveTxt">.</div>

  <br> <br> iframe:<br>

  <iframe id="iFrameZ2" src="z2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
window.onmessage = e =>
  {
  receiveTxt.textContent = e.data
  /* ----------------------
  if (e.data==='scroll')
    {
    document.querySelector('#xyz').scrollTop
    }
  ------------------ */
  }
btSender.onclick = _ =>
  {
  let info = messageTxt.value.trim()
  if (info!='')
    iFrameZ2.contentWindow.postMessage( info,'*')
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> file **z2.html** (iframe)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h6>z2.html</h6>
  <input id="msgTxt" type="text" placeholder="send a message">
  <button id="btSender">send msg</button>
  <p id="getMsg">...</p>
<script>
btSender.onclick=_=>
  {
  let info = msgTxt.value.trim()
  if (info!='')
    window.parent.postMessage(info,'*')
  }
window.onmessage = e =>
  { 
  getMsg.textContent = e.data 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```