# iframe: How to display raw (plain text) html?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, nuxt.js

I want to display an HTML string as raw/plain text HTML in an iframe.

For example, display "`<b>Hello World</b>`" (instead of **Hello World**).

I've tried to display it like this:

`<iframe srcdoc="<pre><b>Hello World</b></pre>"></iframe>`

But it didn't work. It displays bold "Hello world" text.

I'm using Nuxt.js.

What am I missing?

Comment: your iframe content must be an other html file. se a sample code => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170585/scope-issue-with-iframe/69171007#69171007

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I want to be able to display plain html that comes from the database. So I don't want to create a separate html file

Comment: no separate HTML file == no iFrame

Comment: It looks like your example shows a trick how to communicate between the parent page and the iframe. I do not need it, I only need to render an iframe with html content (as plain text). With the code above I'm able to render the iframe, the only problem that it renders HTML, not a plain text

Comment: Yes my example show this trick because it ie an answer to this kind of communication. but it also show how to use iFrame with your own contents

Comment: Why do you even need this one? Can you please explain the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no iframe

```html
<pre id="code"></pre>

<script>
  document.getElementById('code').textContent = '<b>Hello World</b>';
</script>
```

With an iframe

```html
<iframe id="codeFrame"></iframe>

<script>
  function writeToIframe(iframe, markup) {
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write('<pre id="code"></pre>');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('code').textContent = markup;
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
  }

  writeToIframe(document.getElementById('codeFrame'), '<b>Hello World</b>');
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, it helped a lot!