# Form in an iframe is not define : Edge issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

setting value to a form in iframe and submit the form.

```
window.frames['equityIFrame'].document.forms[0].[actionParam] = "equityAction";
window.frames['equityIFrame'].document.forms[0].submit();
```

This code works fine in IE and other browser.

In Edge browser, throws the below error.

**cannot read the property 'forms' of undefined.**

What will be the work around for this.

Comment: Try the correct way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291094/iframe-how-to-display-raw-plain-text-html

Comment: Hi @user630209 How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296530/form-in-an-iframe-is-not-define-edge-issue/69309202#69309202) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) to access the iframe's document and its internal DOM. You can refer to my sample code below, it works well in Edge and other browsers:

**iframe.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="form.html" id="test"></iframe>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="ChangeIframe()" />
    <script>
        function ChangeIframe() {
            document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.document.getElementById("fname").value = "myname";
            document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**form.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.html" method="get">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```