# Can you target an element in an iFrame from the same site?

Tags: javascript, iframe

What I'm trying to do is to is to open the minicart url in an iframe on a page so i can get the basket total from the cart. i've been able to do this, but when i try to target what's on the iframe i'm unable to do so. On the site when i console.log "pre" i do see that in the html collection the innerHTML does display what is outputted. Any idea how or if i would be able to target this?

```js
var iframevar = document.getElementById('freeGiftiFrame');
var elmnt = iframevar.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
console.log(elmnt)
```

```html
<iframe id="freeGiftiFrame" class="cartPopout" name="iframe_a" height="100px" width="100%">
  <html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
      {"miniCartCount": 1, "miniCartPrice": "€&nbsp;30,00"}
      </pre>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: You can't define iframe contents like this; child nodes of an `<iframe>`tag were historically where you'd put the "your browser doesn't support iframes" text.  Instead you either need to use a `src` attribute pointing to a URL, or a `srcdoc` attribute containing the HTML for the child page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scope issue with iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170585/scope-issue-with-iframe)

Comment: Allready answering here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170585/scope-issue-with-iframe/69171007#69171007   you need to use [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Hi @DanielBeck sorry should have been clearer, what i'm showing is just how the iframe appears on the page itself. It has been inserted using src pointing to the url page. Just wasn't sure how to show what i was trying to do.

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks will take a look, what i'm trying to do though is to get the innerHTML of what's in pre. I can target this element to hide it for eg but unable to get the inner content.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry to be pedantic @leek1234. THere's nothing particularly dangerous about what you're doing here, so long as you control the contents of both the parent and the child window. I believe you should be able to do this if you set `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` on the iframe, but I haven't confirmed (SO blocks this in its snippets)

Comment: The only thing on the page in the iframe I'm opening up is literally the code that I've copied into the snippet above showing the product count & basket total. If it was a full blown website then i'd consider otherwise. Will take a look at sandbox thanks!

Comment: Adding in sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" looks to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the issue adding in = sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" does the trick for me